# How to get array values from view (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

i would like to ask for your help to solve my problem. Your help is kindly appreciated.
My question is i have two inputs type which are array `( <input type='text' name='cost[]'> and <input type='text' name='price[]'> )` in view. Both inputs type are within a foreach statement. Let's say foreach from a table of database that has 3 records. So, from the view of web browser it requires user to input 3 times on the cost and price fields for every record. In my controller, i want to compare user input as below

```
-price[1] cannot be more than cost[1] 
-price[2] cannot be more than cost[2]
-price[3] cannot be more than cost[3]
```

by using if else statement. How am i going to code in my controller so that price[1] is only compared to cost[1], price[2] is only compared to cost[2] and price[3] is only compared to cost[3].Below is my code in my controller, but cannot work.

```
 $cost = $this->input->post('cost');
 $price = $this->input->post('price');

if ($price > $cost)
{ 
  echo "Rejected";
}
else
{
  echo "Accepted";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to loop over all the values.
My Codeigniter is a little rusty but I believe $cost and $price should both be arrays. Some something simple like this;

```
foreach ($price as $key => $value) {
    if ($value > $cost[$key] ) {
        echo "Rejected";
    } else {
        echo "Accepted";
    }
}
```

If you want all to be valid then you could just break on the first rejected value. Otherwise you loop through all and warn the user about the invalid ones?

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below.

> For demo: [Demo URL](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/71fecba274303fb9a646265aa300a505b99fb9e9)

```
<?php 


//$cost = $this->input->post('cost');
//$price = $this->input->post('price');

//Suppose I have added dummy values in these variable as you received from view.

$cost = array(1,2,3);
$price = array(3,4,1);

//as you mentioned each one cost have price like $cost zero index compared with $price zero index. 

$i = 0;
foreach($cost as $cos){

  if ($price[$i] > $cos)
  { 
    echo "Rejected";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Accepted";
  }
  $i++;
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: It's my pleasure. This should be a accepted answer.